# Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed

Tags: swift3, alamofire

getting error... i don't know how to fix it please help me

```
APIError<jsonError>(request: Optional(https://www.abcd.com/mobile_app/cell_action.php/?action=brand_slider_homepage), response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60800042bd20> { URL: https://www.abcd.com/cell_app/mobile_action.php/?action=brand_slider_homepage } { status code: 200, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "PUT, GET, POST";
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=60, private, must-revalidate";
Connection = close;
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 1630;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Mon, 03 Apr 2017 07:17:43 GMT";
Expires = "Mon, 10 Apr 2017 07:17:43 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.4.17 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4";
Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.30";
} }), data: Optional(16487 bytes), error: Optional(Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableContentType(acceptableContentTypes: ["application/json"], responseContentType: "text/html"))), errorModel: Optional(abcd.HomeBrandVIewCell.jsonError))
```

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Server sends "text/html" in response while you have set and expected json:

> acceptableContentTypes: ["application/json"], responseContentType: "text/html"

You need then to custom your HTTP body. Try out this link in GitHub :
[urlrequestconvertible](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#urlrequestconvertible)